# When @Value annotation assigns value to the variable?

Tags: spring-boot

When `@Value` annotation in spring boot assigns value to the respective variable.
As in java constructor initializes the variables of that class if I am not wrong. so just want to know how it works in case if I am using value annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may already know, you can only use `@Value` annotation within classes annotated with `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Configuration`, `@Repository` and other `stereotype` and `@Configuration` annotations. The `stereotype` annotations are;

> Annotations denoting the roles of types or methods in the overall
>   architecture (at a conceptual, rather than implementation, level).

as per the [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/package-summary.html).

Once you decorated a class with one of this annotation (one class could have one of these annotation hence it's define a conceptual role for the class), at runtime, each of the `stereotype` class get initialized by the Spring `ApplicationContext`. This is a eager loading, so every bean and `stereotype` class get initialized and store in the memory to `wire/inject` whenever it needs.

This is where `@Value` annotation comes to the picture. When the classes are initializing, if there're **instance** variables annotated with `@Value` annotation, `@Value` annotation resolve the expression (SpEL) from `ApplicationContext` and inject the property value to the variable if the property resides in default config file(`application.yml` or `application.properties`).

---

**Note**: You have to define annotation `@PropertySource("classpath:/com/${my.placeholder:default/path}/app.properties")` with your property file if you want to add additional properties' files.